# sorting a contingency table in R by name

Tags: r

I have a contingency table t  like

0    1   10   11   12   13   14    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

3780 3502  433  316  284  168   74 2104 1930 1560 1482  868  691  645  575

When I do names(t), I get

[1] "0"  "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"

which means that the names of the rows are strings of integers. I would like to sort the table so that the order is 0,1,2,3,..etc. How can I do this. I tried order(names(t)) but that dos not give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `order` on the `names` converted to `numeric`

```
t1 <- t[order(as.integer(names(t)))]
```